# Recovering a function from a given volume where the volume is is a known function

Tags: calculus

> A solid is generated by rotating about the x-axis the region under the curve $y=f(x)$, where $f$ is a positive function and $x≥0$.  The volume generated by the part of the curve from $x=0$ to $x=b$ is $2^b$ for all $b >0$.  Find the function $f$.

I understand solids of revolution fairly well and I've managed to set up the following equality:

$$\pi \int_0^b f^2(x)dx = 2^b$$

After some fiddling I am able to discover a function, $f(x) = \sqrt{ln(2)2^x/\pi}$, however when I plug this function back into the formula for the solid of revolution I always get a value which is equal to $2^b -1$ for all b>0.

How do I compensate for the missing one?

Comment: The equality you have written cannot be correct because when $b\rightarrow 0$, the left hand side is $0$ whereas the right hand side is $1$

Comment: I see. How could I set up an equality that is valid in this case? @RohanDidmishe